# Installing Lightning Add-On on Thunderbird

Tags: 14.04, thunderbird, lightning

I attempted to install The Lightning plugin for Thunderbird.  I do this by going to Tools -> Add-ons.  I search for Lightning and click "Add to Thunderbird".  Then I get a popup asking me if I want to open or save this .xpi file.  If I click open, then Thunderbird opens a new email address with the .xpi file attached.  If I click save, then try to double click it, it again opens as an email in Thunderbird.  How do I install this dang thing?!

I attached two screenshots for clarification.
[image: open or save xpi file]
[image: xpi opens as an email]

Comment: can you try to drag and drop the xpi file from nautilus onto thunderbird's add-ons screen?

Comment: ahh hah!  yes I can, that worked!  If you want to add this as an answer I will mark it as an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After download .xpi file, open Thunderbird.

Open the Add-ons Manager ( Tools -> Add-ons )

Just drag the `.xpi` file from nautilus, and drop it in the Add-ons Manager, then it should start installing.

Answer (score 4):

**Since Thunderbird version 60, Lightning is integrated in Thunderbird and no longer just an add-on.**

But, unfortunately, for now, on Linux you still need to install the package separately. Hopefully this won't be the case for long...

So here is **how to get the Lightning calendar on Thunderbird >= v60** if it was not installed directly along with Thunderbird:

If you have/had lightning already as an add-on, start with step 1. If you newly install Thunderbird or did not have Lightning installed as an add-on before, start at step 3.:

1. In Thunderbird go to `Tools > Add-ons > Extensions`
2. `Remove` the Lightning add-on (don't worry, your calendar configurations will not disappear).
3. Close Thunderbird
4. Open a terminal and enter:
   `apt-get install xul-ext-lightning` (you might need `sudo ...`)
5. Launch Thunderbird again and you should be good to go.